# Loading Laravel blase views using Vue

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel project with a dashboard that contains a side menu. When navigating through this side menu, it refreshes the whole page (layout & view in blade). This is my dashboard:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufPWd.png)

I want to know how I'm able to load my blade views without page refresh. So that when I'm clicking on a navigation link, only the yielded content changes. How am I able to achieve this? Please don't mark this as a dublicate as I've visited most of the similar topics but without any succes.

Oh, and I'd appriciate it so bad if there's someone that's willing to help me out using Teamview.

Answer (score 0):

views cannot be loaded that way with `laravel`. you will need to use components to design your pages with vue. with components in place you can now use vuerouter to load your pages that way.

Comment: Is there any up to date tutorial that you can recommend me to watch? I'm trying to follow the DRY principle as much a possible.

Comment: I have a book that i bought. if you don't mind i can share with you. it is titled full stack laravel and vuejs

Answer (score 0):

Run `php artisan preset vue` to start your project using Vue.

To access a menu link without refresh the page, use `<route-link to="..."></route-link>`

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html